# PHP: Display number of links based on variable

Tags: php

I have a variable `$h`, which counts the number of properties in my `foreach`. I then have a number stored in `$nb_elem_per_page` to limit the number of properties shown per page.

```
<?php $sum_total = ceil($h / $nb_elem_per_page); ?>
```

I then use the above to work out how many pages these will need. For example `$nb_elem_per_page` is currently 12. So if `$h` was 123 it would need 11 pages.

Is there a way for me, using the number from `$sum_total` create links for the number here, such as:

```
http://www.website.co.uk/properties/search/?bed=4&go=1
http://www.website.co.uk/properties/search/?bed=4&go=2
http://www.website.co.uk/properties/search/?bed=4&go=3
```

So it outputs the number of links based on the number in `$sum_total`, but on each one the end number goes up 1 each time as above? This would then be my pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $sum_total; $i++) {
    echo "<a href=\"http://www.website.co.uk/properties/search/?bed=4&go={$i}\">{$i}</a>";
}
```

Or whatever you would like.
You can refer to php's documentation here : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php